# Spawning selected character once the game start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, selected, spawn

I'm making characters selection UI, and it works perfectly, but I have a problem, I can't display my selected character in scene level, though I'm using player preferences to stock the index of selected player. I also made an empty game object in both scenes and it contains characters that I selected them:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class _CharaChoose : MonoBehaviour 
{
   private GameObject[] charactersList;
   private int index;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () 
   {
       index = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CharacterList");
       charactersList = new GameObject[transform.childCount]; //Numero ta3 child
       for (int i = 0; i <= transform.childCount; i++) 
       {
          charactersList [i] = transform.GetChild (i).gameObject; //Filling our array with gameObjects
       }

       // we toggle of their renderes by accessing to the array
       foreach (GameObject go in charactersList) 
       {
          go.SetActive (false);
       }

       if (charactersList [index])
        charactersList [index].SetActive (true);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }

    public void Toggleleft()
    { //Toggle off the current model
        charactersList[index].SetActive(false);

        index--;
        if (index < 0)
            index = charactersList.Length - 1;

            //Toggle on the new model
            charactersList[index].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ToggleRIght()
    {   charactersList [index].SetActive (false);
        index++;
        if (index == charactersList.Length)
            index = 0;
        charactersList [index].SetActive (true);
    }

    public void ConfirmButton()
    {   
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CharacterList", index);
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("newStuff");
    }
}
```

Comment: Lot of help that this question will yield ..how is anybody supposed to know what it is you're doing or not doing when you haven't displayed and code that pertains to your current problem and or issue...?

Comment: i tried to share it ,but i couldnt i dont where is the problem :/

Comment: Here is it mate !

Comment: This is the code for your character selection script right? The problem likely rest in how you call it in the next scene so could you show us that? Also if you are just doing this to save the selected character between scene, I would advise to use a master class containing a [DontDestroyOnLoad()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) method

Comment: Well,in my 2nd scene,i have game object which is parent of my characters and i attached to it this script,i tried with DontDestroyOnLoad() but i had any thing !